# Behavior of GCD async method not understandable

Tags: ios, multithreading

I have this below in my iOS app.
I am learning GCD. so, trying out the simple things.

Here, The output of this is confusing me.
Why always the 2. set of statements are coming first and then 1.?
Even though I am dispatching the two tasks to GCD, first I am dispatching 1. set first. It is not really a huge task so that 1. set and 2.set will overlap in time.  Its just a simple task to print what threads it is running on.

I have run it several times expecting that it would give different results as how it happens in threading environment.

Please describe.

```
2. Crnt Thread = <NSThread: 0x10920fee0>{name = (null), num = 1}
2. Main thread = <NSThread: 0x10920fee0>{name = (null), num = 1}
1. Crnt Thread = <NSThread: 0x10920fee0>{name = (null), num = 1}
1. Main thread = <NSThread: 0x10920fee0>{name = (null), num = 1}
3. Crnt Thread = <NSThread: 0x10920fee0>{name = (null), num = 1}
3. Main thread = <NSThread: 0x10920fee0>{name = (null), num = 1}
```

Code here:

```
void displayAlertView(void *paramContext)
{

    NSLog(@"3. Crnt Thread = %@",[NSThread currentThread]);
    NSLog(@"3. Main thread = %@", [NSThread mainThread]);
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    AlertViewData *contextData = (AlertViewData *)malloc(sizeof(AlertViewData));
    dispatch_async(myQueue,^(void){
        NSLog(@"1. Crnt Thread = %@",[NSThread currentThread]);
        NSLog(@"1. Main thread = %@", [NSThread mainThread]);
    });
    if(contextData != NULL)
    {
        NSLog(@"2. Crnt Thread = %@",[NSThread currentThread]);
        NSLog(@"2. Main thread = %@", [NSThread mainThread]);

        dispatch_async_f(myQueue, contextData, displayAlertView);
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "2" statements come first because that code is getting executed before the asynchronous block has had a chance to be setup and run. That's the whole point of `dispatch_async`. Such code gets run on another thread while the current thread continues on its merry way.

If you updated both blocks of code to use a loop that logs 100 logs statements, then you would probably see some mixing of "1" and "2" statements.

But with just the two logs, they happen so fast, the "2" logs complete before the block with the "1" logs has had a chance to kick in. Look at the timestamps in the log to see.

**UPDATE**

The above was written under the assumption that `myQueue` was a background queue. As Martin pointed out, it's the main queue. Since it is the main queue, the answer is quite a bit different.

Since you are doing asynchronous calls on the main queue, everything is done on the same main thread. Each call to `dispatch_async` is like adding it to the end of the line.

The currently running code is at the head of the line. When you call `dispatch_async` for the block with the "1" logs, that block is added to the end of the line and will be run when the current code is done. Then you call the `dispatch_async_f` for the "3" logs. Those get added to the end the line (after the "1" logs).

So once the current runloop completes (and the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method returns), then the next bit in line is run. This is your "1" logs. When that is done, the next block in the queue is run (your "3" logs).

Comment: Not completely correct I think. The block is dispatched to the *main* queue which runs only on the main thread. It is executed when didFinishLaunchingWithOptions returns because that is a serial queue.

Comment: @rmaddy: Can you please explain in detail?  Does GCD blocks give more overhead on the processor core than calling a normal function?  Is that why 2 set of statements are first scheduled to run?

Comment: @MartinR Oops - I overlooked that `myQueue` is the main queue. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Chandu I completely updated my answer after Martin pointed out that your queue is for the main queue and not a background queue.

Comment: @rmaddy: Thanks for your explanation.  If main queue is the only that I can use for UI related tasks and if main queue is serial?  Then, won't I be able to do two UI operations at a time? Like moving two different views in two different paths etc.?

Comment: @Chandu If you update your question with what you really want to do, someone may be able to offer suggestions.

Comment: @rmaddy: What if I want to move two or more UIViews - like some simple animations at a time?

Comment: At this point you really have a completely different question. I would suggest that you close this one out and post a new, specific question about what you need help with. Be sure you include what you have tried and what issue you need help with.

Comment: @rmaddy: thank you! I raised one more question: please see that too!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23714950/gcd-two-parallel-animations-on-uiviews