# GCD: two parallel animations on UIViews

Tags: ios, multithreading

I came from this post, as the discussion is too much deviated from the main question.
[Behavior of GCD async method not understandable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23714718/behavior-of-gcd-async-method-not-understandable)

Please help,

My iPad application has two side by side TableViews.
These two have to load the data in real time from two different web services. 
I would like to have two threads - each dedicated to one tableview. 
As dispatch_get_main_queue would give me only a serial one, I will not be really able to update the tables in real time.  And, also it involves updating UI elements, I have to only do the threading on the main queue, which is serial - making the parallel fetch not possible.

Can someone please add your thoughts and let me how can I have two separate threads running concurrently and updating the UI elements?

Comment: Have a look at "Animations" in the "View Programming Guide for iOS" and at the "Core Animation Programming Guide". There are dedicated methods to animate views and layers.

Comment: @MartinR: Please, see this scenario. I have changed my question. If you had down voted this question, can you please reset that down voting?

Comment: I did not vote on this question. - But you should describe your problem more clearly, it seems to be unrelated to UView *animations*. Note that you can fetch data on a background thread and only do the UI update on the main thread when the data has arrived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask:

> Can someone please add your thoughts and let me how can I have two separate threads running concurrently and updating the UI elements?

You can simple have those thread do their requests and parsing in the background threads, and then have them dispatch the model and UI updates back to the main queue.

For example, you could do something like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
   // issue first web service request

   // when done, update the UI

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       // update the model here

       // also issue the `reloadData` (or whatever table updates you want) 
       // for the first table view
   });
});
```

and

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
   // issue second web service request

   // when done, update the UI

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       // update the model here

       // also issue the `reloadData` (or whatever table updates you want) 
       // for the second table view
   });
});
```

These two will run concurrently (because all global queues are concurrent queues), but UI/model updates will be dispatched to the main queue, which will ensure everything stays synchronized, that UI updates happen successfully, etc. Thus you enjoy the concurrency offered by background queues, but you'll take advantage of the serial main queue where you need to.

Clearly, the above assumes that you're dispatching the network requests to some background queue (and we'll use the default global queue), but the precise mechanism for issuing asynchronous network requests can vary greatly (and might not involve any dispatching at all). If you need specific counsel, you should share precisely how you're issuing the requests to your web services (e.g. AFNetworking? `NSURLConnection` (and if `NSURLConnection`, one of the convenience methods or delegate based approach)? `NSURLSession`?), as the implementation details will vary based upon how you're making the request.

But the idea is simple: Perform the network service requests asynchronously, and then make sure that upon the completion of the request, you perform the resulting model and UI updates on the main queue. This way, you enjoy the concurrency of the requests, but the UI updates happen on the main queue.

Comment: Hi Rob. Thanks!  Inside the main dispatch_async, shouldn't that be dispatch_sync() because after the initialisation I want to update my UI. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Chandu You can use `dispatch_sync` if you want, but it's unnecessary here. I would generally advise `dispatch_async` unless there was a compelling need not to (i.e., you have something immediately after the dispatch that shouldn't start until the dispatched code finishes). But that's not the case here (at least in my example code). But the difference between `dispatch_sync` and `dispatch_async` is not significant here, so it's a bit academic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can only update the UI on the main thread.

If you use `UIView animateWithDuration:... animations:...` you can place multiple animation on multiple different views in the animation block for them to run concurrently. You can also call `animateWithDuration:animations:` repeatedly.

For layers, you can use `CAAnimationGroup` to group animation for concurrent execution.

In any case you shouldn't be using (or trying to use) GCD for UI animation.

Comment: I have changed my question. Please see

Comment: So it's a completely different question... The web services will not return data at the same time so expecting concurrent UI update is wrong. See the comment from @MartinR for what you should do.

Comment: I mentioned two different web services.  If these are all single core processor nothing will happen at a given minimum possible time slice. But when we do have cores, it is possible that two things can happen on different cores at a given time.

Comment: You're talking about both macro time (network response) and micro time (clock cycles) like they're the same thing. Do you actually have a problem because what you describe isn't a problem, it's an invalid concern.